# Joining two DataTables top to bottom in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, merge, dataset

I have two  datatables

```
Dt1-
a b c d
e f g h
Dt2
a1 b1 c1 d1
e1 f1 g1 h1
```

I am trying to concatenate these two into creating another datatable as-

```
Dt1    
    a b c d
    e f g h
    a1 b1 c1 d1
    e1 f1 g1 h1
```

I am doing  dt1.merge(dt2). It is overwriting the d1 and just giving output as the values of dt2. 
Is there a method for this or I have to add dt2 to dt1 row by row like the below method?

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt2.Rows) {
dt.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);
}
```

Comment: Is the schema the same?

Comment: Yes the schema is exactly the same. Datatabe.merge is overwriting my previous data. I am not sure why this is happening.

Comment: Are primary keys defined? In that case the `RowState` of each `DataRow` is used to determine the row that will be used. You should explicitly call `DataTable.AcceptChanges` before to set their state to `Unchanged`. Apart from that, if the loops works, use that. Note that you can also use `DataTable.ImportRow` instead of the `ItemArray`-approach.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I had definied the primary key as the first column of each datatable. Are you suggesting that the changes I made in creating the primary key are not saved and I have to call acceptchanges?

Comment: So are the same PK's in both tables? If so, what you want to with these duplicates?

Comment: @TimSchmelter  No they are not duplicates. I have set up primary keys to first column in both the tables. I am querrying the db and getting a datatable and that query is in loop so I am getting a datatable each time and I have to join all the datatables top to bottom as above.

Comment: Are you sure that you can't do the join/`UNION ALL` in database? That would be the best option.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes that can be done. But my query retrieves some million records and it will be again slower if i do a join in the query. It already has some 4 joins. Isnt there any manipulation possible at the DataTable level after i retrieve the data?

Comment: You can use database-paging(e.g. via `ROW_NUMBER` in SQL-Server), on that way you wouldn't select all records at once.  Can you provide sample data (the code that creates the `DataTable` manually) that reproduces this `Merge` behaviour?

Comment: I have a query q = "select * from db1"; Then the execute function generates a dataset: execute(query). I am passing that dataset.

Comment: I'm not sure if you've answered my last comment. Can you reproduce this behaviour with sample data like above? I have created two datatables with your sample data, defined the first column as primary key but get the desired result of 4 rows with `table1.Merge(table2);`.

Answer (score 0):

use union for union the sets of rows (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358407(v=vs.110).aspx)
Then you can go for the following

```
var rows = dt1.Rows.Union(dt2.Rows).ToArray();
var res = new DataTable();

Array.ForEach(res, (r) => res.Rows.Add(r) );
```

Comment: This will work and it requires adding row by row to dt1. But my table has some million rows and isnt there a function like merge which add the table to the bottom of a table.

Comment: could you please tell me what are you going to do with the result table?

Comment: I am printing it to a tab delimited file.

Comment: so that a DataTable object is not a "have to". What about a IEnumerable<YouDataRow> instead of DataTable? if it suits you fine then the answer will be the first line in my answer. or even var rows = dt1.Rows.Union(dt2.Rows) will be enough.

Comment: Isnt there a method like merge to add a table to the bottom of another with same schema.

Comment: I have googled "DataTable megre" I got a pillow of references, that might be used by you, but, frankly talking, I strongly beleve that for printing data to a file you do not have to go through the joining two table results in a single one. Isn't be easiear and resource cheaper to join the file content from both dt sequentially? Anyway the final decision is up to you! :)